# Calculate $\sqrt[4]{X}$ for the Pauli $X$ gate

Tags: pauli-gates

I was trying to build a $cccx$ gate. According to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) by Berenco et al., it requires a $\sqrt[4]{X}$ gate. Furthermore, I found another [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511250) by Muradian and Frias with this formula:

$$\sqrt A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2i}}(iI+A).$$

From this I calculated $\sqrt[4]{X}$,
$$ \sqrt[4]{X} = \begin{bmatrix}{\frac{2+i}{2}}&{\frac{-i}{2}}\\{\frac{-i}{2}}&{\frac{2+i}{2}}\end{bmatrix} $$

I am not sure about the result at all! I used MATLAB to determine the fourth power of $\sqrt[4]{X}$ matrix, but it doesn't give $X$ matrix. Also, I am confused because there should be four matrices, and I don't know how to implement them in Qiskit either.

Comment: You used their Eq. (9) to compute the square root twice. This is not valid. This equation only holds for a self-inverse $A$, aka it only applies when $A^2=I$. That is true of $X$, but it is not true of $\sqrt{X}$, so you can't use Eq. (9) the second time to get the forth root. You instead need to directly use their Eq. (7).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have found the solution!

Comment: @JahanClaes is eqn. (7) of Muradian and Frias really valid for $\sqrt X$, where we know that $\sqrt X^4=\mathbb I$?  Muradian and Frias state that eqn. (7) is for self-inverse gates ($A^2=\mathbb I$), but I think, naively, the relation between $A$ and $e^{f(A)}$ is slightly different when $A^2\ne\mathbb I$ but $A^4=\mathbb I$.

Comment: @MarkS Eq. (7) is for self-inverse gates, but it is a formula for the $n$th root. So use $n=4$ on $X$, not $n=2$ on $\sqrt{X}$.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!  But can Eq. (7) be generalized to other operators such as any old arbitrary fourth root of $I$?  For example, a quarter-turn clockwise (or counterclockwise) rotation of a square?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you might do this calculation directly. I'd start by finding the spectral decomposition of $X$:
$$
X=|+\rangle\langle +|-|-\rangle\langle -|=e^{i0}|+\rangle\langle +|+e^{i\pi}|-\rangle\langle -|.
$$
The fourth root of the operator is just the same thing but replacing the eigenvalues with their fourth roots:
$$
\sqrt[4]{X}=e^{i0/4}|+\rangle\langle +|+e^{i\pi/4}|-\rangle\langle -|.
$$
So, as a matrix, this is
$$
e^{i\pi/8}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\frac{\pi}{8} & -i\sin\frac{\pi}{8} \\
-i\sin\frac{\pi}{8} & \cos\frac{\pi}{8}
\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, sir